# How do I read a nested structure from solr?

Tags: solr

I am lost and need your advice. I have a nested Solr Document containing multiple levels of sub-documents. Here is a JSON example so you can see the full structure:

```
{
  "id": "Test Library",
  "description": "example of nested document",
  "content_type": "library",
  "authors": [{
      "id": "author1",
      "content_type": "author",
      "name": "First Author",
      "books": [{
         "id": "book1",
         "content_type": "book",
         "title": "title of book 1"
      }],
      "shortStories": [{
         "id": "shortStory1",
         "content_type": "shortStory",
         "title": "title of short story 1"
      }]
      },
      {
      "id": "author2",
      "content_type": "author",
      "name": "Second Author",
      "books": [{
         "id": "book1",
         "content_type": "book",
         "title": "title of book 1"
          }],
      "shortStories": [{
          "id": "shortStory1",
          "content_type": "shortStory",
          "title": "title of short story 1"
       }]
    }]
}
```

I want to query for a document and retrieve the nested structure. I tried using the ChildDocumentTranformerFactory but it flattened the result to be just Library and all other documents as children:

```
{
  "id": "Test Library",
  "description": "example of nested document",
  "content_type": "library",
  "_childDocuments_":[
      {"id": "author1",
      "content_type": "author",
      "name": "First Author"
      },
      {"id": "book1",
      "content_type": "book",
      "title": "title of book 1"
      },
      {
       "id": "shortStory1",
       "content_type": "shortStory",
       "title": "title of short story 1"
       },
     {
     "id": "author2",
     "content_type": "author",
     "name": "Second Author"
     },
    {
     "id": "book1",
     "content_type": "book",
     "title": "title of book 1"
     },
     {
     "id": "shortStory1",
     "content_type": "shortStory",
     "title": "title of short story 1"
     }
   ]
}
```

Here are the query parameters I used:

```
q={!parent which='content_type:library'}
df=id
fl=*,[child parentFilter='content_type:library' childFilter='id:*']
wt=json
indent=true
```

What is the best way to read the nested structure from Solr? Do I need to do some sort of faceting?

I am using Solr version 5.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately solr does not support that right now.

> ChildDocTransformerFactory returns all descendant documents of each parent document matching your query in a **flat list** nested inside the matching parent document

Not sure if there is a work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into Block Join to virtually relate the parent and child.

https://github.com/lucidworks/solrj-nested-docs

Comment: can you please provide an example of creating a virtual relation?